# Google Search with RoR, how make it works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-search, google-search-api

I am new to RoR, and I wonder how I can do a google search by using a field in view of my project, anyone know how I could do that?

I have in my application.html.haml the code :

```
 %form#search
  %input
```

How can i implement this?

Comment: That way I can return to the site search for google, and if I return to a page within the environment of the site?? Like Other index.html.haml page??

Answer (score 1):

Set the `action` of your form to `http://www.google.com/search`, the `method` to `get`, and name your `input` field `q`. Something like the following:

```
%form#search(action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get")
  %input(type="text" name="q")
  %input(type="submit")
```

The result will be the normal URL for google searches with the results displayed:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=term1+term2
```

Comment: That way I can return to the site search for google, and if I return to a page within the environment of the site?? Like Other index.html.haml page??